# AngularJS return from $resource callback

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I have the following function in my factory

```
getSource:function(){
            // If not connected to internet
            return LocalStorage.getObject("sourcesAll");
            // If connected to internet

            return SourceRest.getInstance().query().$promise.then(function(data){
                LocalStorage.setObject("sourcesAll",data);
                return data;
            });
        }
```

My SourceRest is just a $resource call

What i want is that if the user is connected to the internet, he downloads the latest data and saves it to his Localstorage and then return it. 
If not connected take the data from the Localstorage and return it.

Return data with the promise is working fine

```
return SourceRest.getInstance().query()
```

Also returning from the localStorage (if something is saved) is working

```
return LocalStorage.getObject("sourcesAll");
```

Can i return my data from the ajax callback or is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by using $q.defer()

```
// If not connected to internet
return LocalStorage.getObject("sourcesAll");
// If connected to internet

var result= $q.defer();

SourceRest.getInstance().query().$promise.then(function(data){
      LocalStorage.setObject("sourcesAll",data);
      result.resolve(data);
});
return result.promise;
```